# Interpolation doesn't rerender in parent component after custom event from child

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, interpolation, two-way-binding

I have select displayed in `v-for` loop:

```
<div v-for="(n, key) in selectedLanguages">
    <select class="input input__col"
            v-model="currentLang[key]"
            @change="changeLanguage(currentLang[key], key)"
            id="lang_select">
        <option value="pl">Polski</option>
        <option value="en">Angielski</option>
        <option value="es">Hiszpański</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

To each select I'm adding changeLanguage method which is:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                currentLang: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeLanguage(value, key) {
                let data = { value, key };
                this.$nuxt.$emit('change::language', data);
            }
        },
        props: ['selectedLanguages']
    }
</script>
```

and it is in child component. In parent I'm listening for this `change::language` event:

```
this.$nuxt.$on('change::language', res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.selectedLanguages[res.key] = res.value;
    console.log(this.selectedLanguages);
```

Although it's working correctly and it's updating `selectedLanguages` array just fine it doesn't rerender interpolation `{{ selectedLanguages }}` in parent. However it's correctly rerendering interpolation `{{ selectedLanguages }}` in child where it's passed by props. Why?

---

It seems like vue doesn't "catch" that `selectedLanguages` array have been changed. It only see when I `.push` or `.pop` this array. Is there something like `apply` method in vue?

I found this link in documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats and added `this.$set(this.selectedLanguages, res.value, res.key);` in parent below my assignment but it didn't fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue

I was doing exacly like above.

The solution is instead

```
this.selectedLanguages[res.key] = res.value;
```

use

```
this.$set(this.selectedLanguages, res.key, res.value);
```

which is basically a bit weird but it works.

Comment: [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) works as well, as does reassigning the entire array.